# Sublime Text command line 'subl' wrong version

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

In mac terminal, when I enter:

`subl -v`

I get `Sublime Text Build 3059`.

In the Sublime Text application it says I am using build 3065.

Does anyone know how to update the command line tool to match the version I'm using?

`subl` is not currently working for me to open files. I'd also like to set it as my default editor for git commits etc, but can't even get it opening files yet. Any help much appreciated—many people seem to be having this problem but no one I can see has identified this version number issue.

Comment: `subl -v` prints `Sublime Text Build 3065` for me on Linux Mint.

Comment: Thanks sergioFC . I'm trying to work out how to update mine to point to the correct build too.